# How to remove newline character from string in Fortran77?

Tags: string, fortran, newline, fortran77

I am specifying a filename to my Fortran77 program from the command line. However, I get a newline character appended to the filename string (obtained using `getarg`).

How can I remove the new line character?

Comment: I temporarily worked around it by adding one extra argument following the filename argument. Then the filename just had lots of spaces in it, which I removed easily in a do loop (trim does not work in f77), and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: see if your compiler has `lnblnk()` for the second issue. the newline is unusual, but since `getarg` is non standard who knows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an alternative to `len_trim` from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1259426/721644 adapted to find the newline character

```
  integer function findnl(s)
    character(len=*) :: s
    integer i

    findnl = len(s)+1
    do i = 1, len(s)
      if (s(i:i) .eq. achar(10)) then
        findln = i
        return
      end if
    end do
  end function
```

After that, change the rest of the string to spaces

```
 l = findnl(str)
 if (l .le. len(str)) str(l:) = " "
```